# Why is my jQuery animation not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I use jQuery animate all the time, but it is failing for some reason this time. It will work it I try to target '$(this).animate' after the closeBtn click, and it will work, kinda.

here is a portion of my html(the relivant parts, and yes I have called the jQuery library)

```
<div id='lightBox' style="opacity:0;">
    <div id='closeBtn'>
    </div>
    <div id='lightBoxContent'>
    </div><!--lightBoxContent-->
</div><!--lightBox-->
```

here is my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
    $('#quoteBtn').click(function()
    {
        $('#lightBox').animate({
            opacity:'1',
            height:'560px'
        }, 300, function() {
            $('#lightBoxContent').html(output);
        });


        $('#closeBtn').click(function()
        {
            //alert('click');
            $('#lightBox').animate({
                opacity:'0'
            }, 300, function() {
                //alert('first animation complete');
                $('#lightBox').animate({
                    height:'0px'
                }, 300, function() {
                    //alert('second animation complete');
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

and my css(it is not really a requirement for this, but I included it for safe measure

```
#lightBox {
    width:780px;
    background-color:white;
    position:fixed;
    margin-left:-400px;
    margin-top:-300px;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    z-index:9999;
    -webkit-box-shadow:  0px 0px 200px 50px ;
    box-shadow:  0px 0px 200px 50px ;
    padding:20px;
}
```

Comment: You only used those ID's once, right ?

Comment: Have you tried console.log("test"); in various steps to see what line your code is breaking down? or have you taken a look at your console to see if there are any errors?

Comment: For things like these, you should also create a jsfiddle. Makes our lives easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to move `$('#closeBtn').click(function()` outside of the click() function being called when #quoteBtn is click. Because it will never be called since you can't click inside of a click.

Here is what it should look like:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
    $('#quoteBtn').click(function()
    {
        $('#lightBox').animate({
            opacity:'1',
            height:'560px'
        }, 300, function() {
            $('#lightBoxContent').html(output);
        });    
    });

    $('#closeBtn').click(function()
    {
        //alert('click');
        $('#lightBox').animate({
            opacity:'0'
        }, 300, function() {
            //alert('first animation complete');
            $('#lightBox').animate({
                height:'0px'
            }, 300, function() {
                //alert('second animation complete');
            });
        });
    });

});
```

**Update:** Ok... here is part 2.

You want to set `$('#lightBox').animate({` to `$('#lightBox').stop().animate({` which will then continue the "close" animation.

Comment: I can't believe I over looked that! But it's still not working.

Comment: Ok think I got it. Updated my answer

Comment: It's an event handler, you don't need to click inside the click, it binds the event on click. Still good point, attaching event handlers inside event handlers is usually not a good idea.

Comment: That you very much doitlikejustin. I ussually only use .stop() on hover events (.mouseenter(), .mouseover(), etc. The event handler inside the event handler wasn't my issue, that was just a typing error. Thanks for your help. On a side note, is it ever a bad idea to put .stop() on a jquery animation? Will it ever mess up the code? I'm thinking about starting to use it by default.

Comment: @MattRyan I can't speak from experience on it being a "bad idea". I almost always use .stop() on any sort of animation, because in the past I have run into many issues **without** using it. But using it has never really messed up my code.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but try changing this:

```
position: fixed;
```

to `position: absolute;` or `position: relative;`

Comment: position:fixed; makes me a little nervous. I know if you don't set an element to position:relative or position:absolute in the css, jQuery won't animate it. Just not sure for position:fixed.

Comment: I used fixed because I always want the panel in focus, so users can't scroll away from it, it's a sort of lightbox.I have used this method before, and fixed works with jquery animate.Yes, all IDs are only used once throughout the document.I use alert() for testing purposes.